# Unknown database and database operation found on my app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I am testing my android app using the android studio also I am using a lot of libraries from GitHub and my problem is when I check LogCat, it showing the unknown message from my phone there is no related app has installed to get this type of message.
What is the problem is my app is hacked?

```
0-23 12:41:56.486 19337-19379/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting imdata={"sender":"1007787459425466","is_video":true,"filesize":4229475,"alias":"aswin ps","original_id":".8HGNxeIGQGYKGdwELDentPbijFS","public_level":1,"sim_iso":"IN","type":"video"} is_public=1 buid=fof:fof object_id=.8HGNxeIGQGYKGdwELDentPbijFS original_id=.8HGNxeIGQGYKGdwELDentPbijFS view_type=1 timestamp=1540262393 group_num=0 message_read=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: stories.buid, stories.object_id (code 2067)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at com.imo.android.imoim.util.v.a(SourceFile:79)
        at com.imo.android.imoim.util.h.doInBackground(SourceFile:1026)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Maybe some library utilizes database and hence the message

Comment: but the message is not related to my phone and apps

Comment: show your libraries.